# Entity last modification date

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults, nsmanagedobject

Is there any solution for getting last modification date of whole Enity? Timestamps of each `NSManagedObject` won't be a good solution because of app sync with web service (some of them would be in database with older date).

I need to make a timestamp for the whole entity every time user decides to update the list so I can present this date in `SSPullToRefresh`.

There is only one solution in my mind: `NSUserDefaults` but is it a good place to keep Entity last modification date?

Comment: You mean you want to record the most recent date when **any** entity was modified?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, exactly!

Comment: Not sure if this will address your requirements but you could observe saves on the managedObjectContext and use that to record a timestamp of the last save.  Alternately centralise a save method for your managedObjectContext and only set the timestamp if hasChanges is also true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to avoid `NSUserDefaults` always feels like mixing apples and oranges.

When I need to store information like this I like to put it in the metadata of the `NSPersistentStore` itself.  That way it is attached to the file that I am syncing with the web service.

There are methods on the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` that allow you to access the metadata and alter it.  Then if the file gets transplanted to another device (say in a restore or something else) the metadata goes with it.

Comment: I really, really like your solution. It's clean, smooth and 'just the way it sould be'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you elaborate how can I get last updated time of Entity ?

Comment: Ahhhh! I got how to use metadata and benefits for storing metadata using NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. 
https://paysonwallach.com/posts/storing-metadata-in-core-data/

Perfect Solution

Comment: Feels like I should be getting royalties from that post :/

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Then that's great ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to create an entity with a sole purpose of tracking modification for entities. it might look something like:

```
LastModified:
    date (NSDate*)
    key (NSString*)
```

You could treat the `key` property as the entity name

You could populate these entities on launch (if needed).
You could also create a global dictionary mapping their `key` to their `objectID` on launch.

The way you use this object is:
When you start your sync operation you fetch the entities that should be updated and set it to the current date, if you know which entities will be updated (reflects reality better).

If not, before you save go over all updated,inserted,deleted sets of the context and make a set of all the entity types that were changed and update the `LastModified` object corresponding to those keys (entity names).

The benefits of this approach are:

1. You only update the "last modified" date if you actually managed to commit/save the sync operation changes
2. You can observe changes in these objects using KVO to update your UI.
3. You don't have to query the store as often as other methods

Disadvantage:

1. If your CoreData entities inherit from one another or you have more than one entity that affect the same `key` (and you don't know what keys would be updated in the sync) it would be more complex to maintain (you might want to use the entity `userInfo` dictionary to store the `key` so that different entities might update the same modification date)

Answer (score 1):

The strategy I've used in the past for this was to look up the most recently modified record for the entity type.

So let's say you have a Contact Entity and you want to sync any changes from the last time you performed synchronization. Query all of your local contact records and sort them by `lastModifiedDate` in descending order. The first result back is the timestamp you want to use when querying your web service.

I used this strategy when writing this tutorial, [How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)

The biggest advantage I have found with this is that you do not need to worry about ensuring that the server time is synced up with the device's local time. If they're off by a few minutes you're not going to "miss out" on anything.

Comment: But is this solution efficent? You have to fetch everything and sort it is a couple MBs of RAM.

Comment: It really depends on your data set, if you're finding that the fetch is too slow you could always persist that timestamp somewhere else while processing the import/sync. `NSUserDefaults` is probably a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it simple and use `NSUserDefaults`. You could add an observer to the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSave` notification. Then, create/update an `NSDate` object using the `NSString` name of the `Class`. I have this in my `AppDelegate`:

**In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mocWillSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification
                                           object:self.managedObjectContext];
```

**Selector**

```
- (void)mocWillSave:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // Get array of classes that have been updated.
    // This way, we don't loop through every updated Object...just the 
    // unique classes in the updatedObjects set.
    NSArray *updatedObjectClasses = [self.managedObjectContext.updatedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"class"];

    for (id obj in updatedObjectClasses) {
        [userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:obj];
    }

    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

**NOTE:** This of course only takes in to account `updatedObjects`. You could of course do this same for `insertedObjects`.